# Nlog не работает ${basedir}

Tags: c#, nlog

Есть проект asp.net для ведения лога использую Nlog, устанавливал через NuGet. В настройках прописал

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
```

Если собирать Debug то лог ведется, но если Release или запускать с localhost, то файл лога в указанной директории не создается.

Если в `failName` жестко указать адрес например `C:\my_log.log`, то файл лога создается во всех случаях.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том что возможно неправильно настроен IIS, не хватает прав на модификацию каталога. Для разных версий IIS пользователи разные, в основном запускается под `NETWORK SERVICE`. Некоторым помогает объявление логгера как `private static`:

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```